# nested for loops with String

Tags: java, string

I am having problems with this method.

It is a constructor with 2 parameters: a name and a String with 100 char called `in`. `in` must be turned in to a array[10][10] with `vak`(an object) in it.

I always get the same exception:

> StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 100

This is the method:

```
 public SpelBord(String naam, String in) {
        int muur=1;
        this.naam = naam;
        System.out.println(in.length());
         for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vakken.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < vakken[j].length; k++) {

                    if (in.charAt(i) == '.') {
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak();

                    }
                    if (in.charAt(i) == 'K') {
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, false, new   Kist());
                    }
                    if (in.charAt(i) == 'D') {
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(true, false);

                    }
                    if (in.charAt(i) == 'M') {
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, false, new Man());



                    }
                     if (in.charAt(i) == '#') {
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, true);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I think it is something with the for loops.
thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` in each `if` statement ?

Comment: why do you manually increment `i` in each if-block?

Comment: I don't understand why you have the 1st for, it's useless if you have vakken instanciated as `new Vak[10][10]`

Comment: could you give more details as to what this code is suppose achieve? Like what is the variable `vakken`?  and why is` i `required to in incremented in each `if` statement?

Comment: Yes that definately is the cause for your error incrementing i inside the dor loop again as others have suggested

Comment: I find that in your code you have checked for characters '.', 'K', 'D', 'M' and '#' What will happen if the character encountered is none of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 100`

**Because:**
Suppose you enter a String of 100 character suppose the string is "**ABCDEFGHIJK . . . . . . LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ**" in that case `in.length=100`
Now see what happens to your code: (Read the comments)

```
for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++) {// i=0
            for (int j = 0; j < vakken.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < vakken[j].length; k++) {

                    if (in.charAt(i) == '.') {//looking for charAt(0)
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak();
                i++;//if this condition satisfies i=1
                    }
                    if (in.charAt(i) == 'K') {//if last if condition satisfies looking for charAt(1)
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, false, new Kist());
                i++;//if this condition satisfies i=2
                    }
                    if (in.charAt(i) == 'D') {//if last if condition satisfies looking for charAt(2)
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(true, false);
                i++;//if this condition satisfies i=3
                    }
                    if (in.charAt(i) == 'M') {//if last if condition satisfies looking for charAt(3)
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, false, new Man());

                                 muur++;
                i++;//if this condition satisfies i=4
                    }
                     if (in.charAt(i) == '#') {//if last if condition satisfies looking for charAt(4)
                        this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, true);
            i++;//if this condition satisfies i=5
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here, in the code the value of your variable `i` increasing unnecessarily. Now think that `i=99` in the loop. Now see what happens in your code:(Read the comments carefully):

```
    for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++) {// i=99
                for (int j = 0; j < vakken.length; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < vakken[j].length; k++) {

                        if (in.charAt(i) == '.') {//looking for charAt(99)
                            this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak();
                    i++;//if this condition satisfies i=100
                        }
                        if (in.charAt(i) == 'K') {
                        //if last if condition satisfies 
                        //looking for charAt(100) 
                        //now charAt(100) dose not exists 
                        //and an error occurs that String out of range
                            this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, false, new Kist());
                    i++;
                        }
                        if (in.charAt(i) == 'D') {
                            this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(true, false);
                    i++;
                        }
                        if (in.charAt(i) == 'M') {
                            this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, false, new Man());

                                     muur++;
                    i++;
                        }
                         if (in.charAt(i) == '#') {
                            this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, true);
                i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I think you understand why the error `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 100` occurs.

To improve your code you can use `else if` ladder and do not increment `i` unnecessarily because `i` is increment in your for loop - `for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++`  . And try to setup/clear the logic before starting coding.

Comment: Thank you I understand my mistake. But there is still something not oke. If I set a counter how much time   this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, true);  it runs. the counter is 3900. I don't know how this can be.. (sorry for my bad sentence construction )

Comment: I couldn't understand your comment (If I set a counter how muth time this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, true);).

Comment: this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, true); It depends on your input String because there is a check [ if (in.charAt(i) == '#') ] . when the character '#' is found in string it executes.

Comment: It's totally depend on your input String.

Comment: Sorry :)  if i set this (int muur=0;) in the beginning of the method and than I set this ( '(in.charAt(i) == '#') {
                            this.vakken[j][k] = new Vak(false, true);
                **++muur;**
                        } ')  (++muur;)                                                    Than at the end of the method I wrote this 'System.out.print(muur);' and when I run it muur = 3900

Comment: Is muur always 3900 ? for different String input in (in) variable?

Comment: this is the input String ########## + #........# + #....D...# + #....K...# + ###......# + #........# + #........# + #....M...# + #........# + ##########

Comment: I deleted 10 # and now its 2900

Comment: That means it depends of your INUPT STRING as I mention earlier

Comment: and this two nested loops [  for (int j = 0; j < vakken.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < vakken[j].length; k++) { ] also helps muur to increment many times.

Comment: If you want to calculate muur, [Count number of '#' * vakken.length * vakken[i].lenght ] multiplication of those three value will help you to count muur

Comment: thank you for the information but i think we can't figger it out. it is something with the the for loops but i don't know what...

Comment: Yes, It is difficult to understand what kind of output you want from your code, but I am just trying understand you why the error occurs in your code which you asked in your question. Hope you understand.

Comment: No output, I just want to make an array vakken[10][10] with objects vak in it. It is a "game world" where a man can move around. after every movement from the man I want to print the game world.

Comment: output means what actually you want to do. a program without output is useless.. Your output is [making an array vakken[10][10] with objects vak in it. It is a "game world" where a man can move around. after every movement from the man I want to print the game world.]

Comment: we learned that output is like void, int,... but the program needs to fill the array[10][10] vakken with vakken and ikt gets the information from the string they get. and isn't there a way to chat normaly? thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The for loops takes care of incrementing the value of i,j. You do not need to do it again.

```
 for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++)
```

`i++` will be executed as the final statement before the loop ends. So will `j++` and `k++` in its respective loops.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should have `continue` statements instead of `i++` in the `if` statements. Then you should not be using the `j` and `k` loops. Instead of that use local variables `j` and `k` initialised to 0 in the `i` loop. In the `if` statements increment the `k` by 1 and check that `k` is less than 10. If `k` is equal to 10 reset `k` to 0 and increment `j` by 1.